# Is the Darboux sum more general than equidistant sum?

Tags: calculus, integration, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

In the definition of Darboux integral of a bounded function $f:[a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, partitions of $[a, b]$ is not restricted to equidistant.

It can be proved that if the upper Darboux sum and lower Darboux sum converges to the same value for equidistant partition of the interval, $f$ is integrable.

Is there a counterexample such that $f$ is Darboux integrable but its equidisant upper Darboux sum and lower Darboux sum don’t converge to same value?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}}(x)$. This is not Riemann Integrable (hence lower and upper Darboux sums will be different for fine enough partitions) The uniform partition converges.

Comment: @OliverDíaz In your example, for any partion, equidistant (uniform) in particular, the lower Darboux sum is equal $0$ while the upper sum is equal $1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: I mean to take the uniform Riemann sums with either of the end points of the subintervals as a tag.

Comment: It can be proved that the upper sum corresponding to equidistant partitions converges to the infimum of all upper Darboux sums when the number of subintervals in equidistant partitions tends to infinity. The same can be proved for lower sums (replace with supremum of all lower Daboux sums here). Now you can conclude.